# Why am I being asked to use the "%" operator when I clearly am?

Tags: javascript

What am I doing wrong isn't "%" the remainder operator

var remainder;

remainder = 11 % 3

On this freecodecamp lesson: (https://learn.freecodecamp.org/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/basic-javascript/finding-a-remainder-in-javascript)

Comment: On this freecodecamp lesson: [link] (https://learn.freecodecamp.org/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/basic-javascript/finding-a-remainder-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

Although not required by JavaScript, it seems the tutorial site requires you to put a semicolon at the end of your  `remainder = 11 % 3` statement.

```
var remainder;
remainder = 11 % 3;  

console.log(remainder)
```

Comment: Thx so much! Really great!

Answer (score 1):

You should get 2 back. It's working correctly.

```
var remainder;
remainder = 11 % 3;

//=> 2
```

If you aren't getting that answer its probably because of the code bootcamp site your using is crap and isn't properly understanding your input. You can prove it works just by using chrome developer console and typing it in there.

Comment: You bet! make sure you mark the answer with the green check mark so I can get awarded points. Cheers.

Comment: Thx so much! Really great!

Answer (score 1):

I agree that it is not required to have a semi-colon, but for the sake of consistency I would include it after every statement, especially while learning a new language.

Comment: Thx so much! Really great!